# Rails API - accessing methods located in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've built a throwaway web app in rails to test out some new concepts. While doing this I created methods that belonged to the model, so as to keep to the principle of keeping controllers light and simple.

However, now I am testing the same app but through a rails API. Can I still keep these methods in the model?

1. I'm not sure how to route the API to access those methods.
2. Because it involves a nested model (contacts through users), I'm not sure where to start even putting it into a controller. Can I make a controller for a nested model?

Here is the user model which gives a taste about what I'm talking about. Most of the methods are essential for the process of adding/accepting and creating contacts.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :contactships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :contacts, -> { where contactships: { status: :accepted }}, through: :contactships
  has_many :requested_contacts, -> { where contactships: { status: :requested }}, through: :contactships, source: :contact
  has_many :pending_contacts, -> { where contactships: { status: :pending }}, through: :contactships, source: :contact
  has_many :blocked_contacts, -> { where contactships: { status: :blocked }}, through: :contactships, source: :contact

  has_many :contactships_inverse, class_name: 'Contactship', foreign_key: :contact_id
  has_many :contacts_inverse, through: :contactships_inverse, source: :user

  has_one_attached :avatar

  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name

  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end

  def all_contacts
    contacts + contacts_inverse
  end

  def has_contactship?(contact)
      #return true if the user is a contact
      return true if self == contact
      contactships.map(&:contact_id).include?(contact.id)
  end

  def requested_contacts_with?(contact)
      return false if self == contact
      #we are going to map requested contacts with list of users to see if they include contact_id
      requested_contacts.map(&:id).include?(contact.id)
  end

  def pending_contacts_with?(contact)
      return false if self == contact
      pending_contacts.map(&:id).include?(contact.id)
  end

  def contacts_with?(contact)
      return false if self == contact
      contacts.map(&:id).include?(contact.id)
  end

  def contact_request(contact)
    #unless the contact is not equal to self and contactship does not already exist
    unless self == contact || Contactship.where(user: self, contact: contact).exists?
        #transaction means that if one fails they both are rolled back
        transaction do
            #for user to another user (sent request)
            Contactship.create(user: self, contact: contact, status: :pending)
            #from another user to user (recieve request)
            Contactship.create(user: contact, contact: self, status: :requested)
        end
     end
  end

  def accept_request(contact)
      transaction do
        Contactship.find_by(user: self, contact: contact, status: [:requested])&.accepted!
        Contactship.find_by(user: contact, contact: self, status: [:pending])&.accepted!
      end
  end

  def reject_request(contact)
      transaction do
        Contactship.find_by(user: self, contact: contact)&.destroy!
        Contactship.find_by(user: contact, contact: self)&.destroy!
      end
  end

end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a call to the controller. Lets consider the below example.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def method_name
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    # Now you can access all the user model methods using @user.model_method_name
    @user.all_contacts
  end

end
```

You need to define the `routes` to this controller in `routes.rb`

You have created `instance methods` in the `user` model. You can access them with the instance of `user`

Comment: Sure, what would the controller be called as it isn't a model by itself? contactships_controller?

Comment: Since you have added the methods in User model. You should call them from users controller, but it is not mandatory. You can create an instance of User in any controller and can access all the methods in that controller

Comment: @JamesStirrat Check the above updated comment and answer

Comment: Yes, but it's not specifically user. It's a nested model/class ```has_many :contactships_inverse, class_name: 'Contactship', foreign_key: :contact_id```

Comment: So as I'm using API, I'll make a contactships controller and move the methods to there?

Comment: No need to move the model methods., just create user instance in any controller and then you can access all the model instance methods.

Comment: Any public methods you define in a model file will be available to any instance of that model throughout your codebase.

Comment: @JamesStirrat don't get hung up on the name of the controller, you can call it anything that describes what it is doing. If it troubles you to call it UsersController, then give it a name you like, as long as the config/routes.rb properly points to the controller. A meaningful description is more important than the (weak) rails naming convention. I sometimes have multiple controllers that control a single model, corresponding with different workflows, better to do that than overload a single controller.